# iOS remote database storage services

Tags: ios, database

I'm new to iOS development, I've just come from web development on MeteorJS. I've been searching for remote database services that work with iOS, but I've only come across CoreData, SQLite and Realm appear to be storage options on the device itself. Please correct me if I'm wrong and if there are remote DB solutions, some suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers,
Clement

Comment: You can just about any web data store; Firebase, Amazon, etc.  CloudKit is provided by Apple

Comment: awesome! I just had a look at Firebase and it seems to do everything I need it to :) Thanks for the recommendation @Paulw11

Answer (score 1):

There is also Apple's own CloudKit. Také a look at WWDC 2014 videos like [this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/208/) and at https://developer.apple.com/icloud/

Comment: Woah nice! there is so much good content on the WWDC page. Thanks for linking through.